# Quandl Error , API Invalid

Tags: pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, data-science, quandl

Screenshot here:

[image: Screenshot here]

Error : Forbidden Error (status 403)
Unable to execute the code . Throws an API error . Trying to display the header of the data using quandl API .

PS : Installed `quandl` in Python3.5 using `pip install quandl`

**CODE**

```
   1> import pandas as pd

   2> import quandl as Q

   3> data = Q.get_table('WIKI/PRICES')

   4> print(df.head())
```

**ERROR**

```
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\quandl\connection.py", line 85,           in handle_api_error
    raise klass(message, resp.status_code, resp.text, resp.headers, code)
quandl.errors.quandl_error.ForbiddenError: (Status 403) (Quandl Error QEPx04) A valid API key is required to retrieve data. Please check your API key and try again. You can find your API key under your account settings.
```

Comment: Try reading the Quandl instructions...

Answer (score 1):

`quandl.ApiConfig.api_key` will need to be set to identify you to Quandl API and to access data.
So signup to [Quandl](https://www.quandl.com/) and get api key and use the same in your code as I shown below:

```
import quandl
quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = '#enter api key here'
data = quandl.get_table('WIKI/PRICES')
print(data.head())
```